# How can I use If controller with Beanshell postprocessor

Tags: jmeter

Here is map what I am looking for :

1. If user login as retailer then follow specific requests
2. If user login as reseller then follow specific requests

What I have done for retailer :

1. I have added one HTTP POST request to login as retailer
2. Also added **BeanShell PostProcessor** to get URL of previous request which will be return by above login post request.
3. I have added following code into **BeanShell PostProcessor** to make sure if returned URL contains any word like "retailer" or not.

**Code :**

```
String URL = prev.getURL().toString();
vars.put("URL", URL);

if (vars.get("URL").contains("retailer")) {
    log.info("PASS");
} else {
    log.info("FAIL");
}
```

Above code works well.

4. Next I have added IF controller and added all **Retailer** related HTTP requests under this IF controller. Now I am not sure what exactly I should write for If controller to tell if previous URL contains word "retailer" then follow all HTTP requests which are under IF controller.

I tried following for IF controller but seems not working :

```
"${URL}".contains("retailer")
```

I feel like jmeter ignoring IF controller as I am not getting any error.

Goal is to execute specific requests based on user role like retailer/reseller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `contains()` function in JavaScript, you need to use [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function instead so your [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) condition should be like:

```
"${URL}".indexOf("retailer") != -1
```

Remember to always look into *jmeter.log* file when your test doesn't work as expected, in 99.9% of cases you can figure out the reason from it.

Comment: Should I tick **Interpret condition as variable expression**.

Comment: For particular your scenario this is not required